# Run a command when system starts for any users

Tags: centos, startup

How can my system run a command every time that it is started?

Is there any script that the system runs when it is starting?

I'm using CentOS 6.2.

Answer (score 0):

Put the script in the /etc/profile.d It will run every time you sign in, thats how we do it for RedHat.